# How can i use React Hooks within Context in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using the following code in my new react-native project, to support Dark Mode using TailwindCSS:

```js
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Appearance } from 'react-native';
import { create } from 'tailwind-rn';
import styles from '../styles.json';

const { tailwind, getColor } = create(styles);
export default tailwind;
export { getColor };

const TailwindContext = createContext({});

const handleThemeClasses = (classes: string, isDarkMode: Boolean) => {
    const regExp = isDarkMode ? /dark:/g : /dark:\S+/g;
    return classes.replace(regExp, "").replace(/\s\s/g, " ").trim();
}

const useTailwind = () => {
    const context = useContext(TailwindContext);
    if (!context) throw new Error(`useTailwind must be used within a TailwindProvider`);

    const [currentColorScheme, setCurrentColorScheme] = context;
    const isDarkMode = currentColorScheme == "dark";

    return {
        isDarkMode,
        setDarkMode: (isDark: Boolean) => setCurrentColorScheme(isDark ? "dark" : "light"),
        tw: (classes: string) => tailwind(handleThemeClasses(classes, isDarkMode)),
        getColor: (colors: string) => getColor(handleThemeClasses(colors, isDarkMode)),
    };
}

const TailwindProvider: React.FC<{}> = ({ children }) => {
    const contextValue = useState(Appearance.getColorScheme());
    return <TailwindContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</TailwindContext.Provider>;
}

export { TailwindProvider, useTailwind }
```

But i get an Typescript Error for this code line:

```js
const [currentColorScheme, setCurrentColorScheme] = context; //Type '{}' is not an array type.
```

How do i need to configure my `createContext` so it will work in Typescript, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use typescript but i usually do it this way.

```
const useTailwind = () => {
    const context = useContext(TailwindContext);
    if (!context) throw new Error(`useTailwind must be used within a TailwindProvider`);

    //do all the deleted stuff in the Provider because you are suppose to return context here.
    return context
}
```

Provider

```
  const [ color, setColor ]  = useState(Appearance.getColorScheme());

//do whatever u need here, and return the value below
   const customFunction = () => 'Hello'

return <TailwindContext.Provider value={{ color, setColor, customFunction }}>{children}</TailwindContext.Provider>;
```

Then i use my hook as

```
 const { color, setColor, customFunction } = useTailwind()
```

and remember to wrap app with TailwindProvider

Typescript example for context

```
export type MyContent = {
  copy: string
  setColor:(c: string) => void
}

export const MyContext = createContext<MyContent>({
copy: 'dark', // set a default value
setColor: () => {},
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed answer. I try to use the hook like this: `const { color } = useTailwind()` but i get another typescript error: `Property 'color' does not exist on type '() => {}'` What do i need to change here, to remove the error?

Comment: i added an typescript example

Answer (score 0):

React's `createContext` is defined with a generic type parameter `T` that describes the context's value. When you do

```
const TailwindContext = createContext({});
```

TS infers that your context has type `{}`. This is the same as explicitly writing it as:

```
const TailwindContext = createContext<{}>({});
```

You should explicitly specify the type parameter. Doing so will require you to provide a `defaultValue` that matches the specified type, but you can generally get away with asserting using `as`, since the default value shouldn't ever be used (as long as you're correctly mounting your context provider higher up in the component tree).

```
export interface TailwindContextType {
  color: string;
  setColor: (color: string) => void;
  customFunction: () => void;
}

const TailwindContext = createContext<TailwindContextType>({} as TailwindContextType);
```

And you would use it like this:

```
const useTailwind = () => {
  const context = useContext(TailwindContext);
  
  // use `null` as the default value when calling `createContext`
  // if you want to include a check like this; if you use `{}`,
  // `context` will be `{}` and this check won't catch it
  // if (!context) throw new Error('...');

  const { color, setColor } = context;
  const isDarkMode = color == 'dark';

  return {
    isDarkMode,
    setDarkMode: (isDark: boolean) => setColor(isDark ? 'dark' : 'light'),
    // ...
  };
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { isDarkMode, setDarkMode } = useTailwind();

  // ...
};
```

You can read more about generic types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i provide a TailwindContextType Interface like yours, i still get the typescript error: `Type 'TailwindContextType' is not an array type.` How can i define an array in the interface, so i can use this code line: `const [currentColorScheme, setCurrentColorScheme] = context;`

Comment: Updated my answer to include sample usage. The error you're seeing is because you're treating `context` like it returns an array like `useState`, but it will return whatever the `Provider` has as its `value` prop (an object, in this case).